# getting compass watch/compile status in a callback

Tags: bash, compass-sass

I'm a little new to compass/ruby/bash so I apologize if I articulate anything incorrectly (or if i'm missing something basic). I'm curious if there is a way for me to access the compass compile status of a file in the compass callback functions.

What do I mean by status of the the compass compile?

when I compass compile through a direct call to compile or via watch I get output as such:

```
identical /my/path/file.css
overwrite /my/path/file.css
unchanged /my/path/file.css
```

I'm curious if I can get access to this information within the on_stylesheet_saved hook. I realize this hook only fires if a file has been saved, but I would like to not run my hook functionality if the file is identical.

so something like:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  if [[ STATUS_OF_COMPILE == 'overwrite' ]]
    //do stuff
  end
end
```

i'm curious how I can get 'STATUS_OF_COMPILE'. At this point I've even tried to see if I can capture the last output in the command line with something like

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  STATUS_OF_COMPILE = ENV['$?']
  #would assume !! contains keyword

  if [[ STATUS_OF_COMPILE == *overwrite* ]]
    //do stuff
  end
end
```

but test is blank. Any ideas/help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Try putting double-quotes on `*overwrite*`

Comment: the problem is that STATUS_OF_COMPILE is empty :(